# How to transform array of string to data model object for MVVM in swift5?

Tags: swift, mvvm, model

This is my Model:

```
struct ListModel: Codable {
   var id: Int
   var name: String
}
```

I have an array of strings and i want to set and transform it this `ListModel`. Any idea?

Comment: where would you get the `id` property from? But in any case, look into [`.map`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017522-map) method

Comment: how is your string formatted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`map(_:)`** on the `String` array to get an array of `ListModel`, i.e.

```
let array = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
array.map { ListModel(id: 0, name: $0) }
```

I've used `0` as the `id's` value for each `ListModel` instance since you didn't specify what it should be in the question.